# How do functional languages model side-effects?

Tags: functional-programming, io, referential-transparency

Since side-effects break referential transparency, don't they go against the point of functional languages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158050/what-are-the-alternative-of-monads-to-use-io-in-pure-functional-programming/2158637#2158637

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two techniques that are used by purely functional programming languages to model side effects:

1) A world type that represents external state, where each value of that type is guaranteed by the type system to be used only once.

In a language that uses this approach the function `print` and `read` might have the types `(string,  world) -> world` and `world -> (string, world)` respectively.

They might be used like this:

```
let main w =
  let w1 = print ("What's your name?", w) in
  let (name, w2) = read w1 in
  let w3 = print ("Your name is " ^ name, w2) in
  w3
```

But not like this:

```
let main w =
  let w1 = print ("What's your name?", w) in
  let (name, w2) = read w in
  let w3 = print ("Your name is " ^ name, w2) in
  w3
```

(because w is used twice)

All built-in functions with side-effects would take and return a world value. Since all functions with side-effects are either built-ins or call other functions with side-effects, this means that all functions with side-effects need to take and return a world.

This way it is not possible to call a function with side-effects twice with the same arguments and referential transparency is not violated.

2) An IO monad where all operations with side effects have to be executed inside that monad.

With this approach all operations with side effects would have type `io something`. For example `print` would be a function with type `string -> io unit` and `read` would have type `io string`.

The only way to access the value of performing operation would be to use the "monadic bind" operation (called >>= in haskell for example) with the IO operation as one argument and a function describing what to do with the result as the other operand.

The example from above would look like this with monadic IO:

```
let main =
  (print "What's your name?") >>=
  (lambda () -> read >>=
  (lambda name -> print ("Your name is " ^ name)))
```

Comment: Your #2 is an implementation detail for your #1.  The IO monad would just automatically carry around that world state for you, packaging and unpackaging it as needed behind whatever syntax your monad uses.

Comment: @JUST: You mean #1 is an implementation detail of #2, no? But then it's not an implementation detail if it's the interface that's exposed to the programmer.

Comment: @JUST: Ok, I get your point, #2 is an abstraction over #1, but that's not necessarily true either. For example languages using monadic IO don't need to implement uniqueness typing to ensure that each world is used only once, as long as they don't expose the world type to the programmer.

Comment: Which one do you prefer? And is there any real advantages/disadvantages? And is there a language that supports both types of IO, especially as you mentioned that 2 is an abstraction of 1? @JUSTMYcorrectOPINION

Answer (score 15):

There are several options available to handle I/O in a functional language.

- Don't be pure.  Many functional languages aren't purely functional.  It's more that they *support*
  functional programming rather than enforcing it.  This is by far the most common solution to the problem
  of I/O in functional programming.  (Examples: Lisp, Scheme, Standard ML, Erlang, etc.)
- Stream transformation.  Early Haskell I/O was done this way.  Check my link below for details if you
  want more information.  (Hint: you probably don't.)
- Continuation-passing I/O (the "world-passing" mentioned in other answers).  In this one you pass a token
  of data around with your I/O that acts as the necessary "different value" to keep referential integrity
  alive.  This is used by several ML dialects if memory serves.
- The "continuation" or "world" thing above can be wrapped in various data types, the most (in)famous
  being the use of monads in this role in Haskell.  Note that this is, notionally, the same thing under
  the covers, but the tedium of keeping track of "world"/"continuation" state variables is removed.

There's [a research dissertation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/functional-programming-input-output/) that exhaustively analyses these.

Functional I/O is an ongoing field of research and there are other languages which address this issue in interesting and mind-mangling ways.  [Hoare logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) is put to use in some research languages.  Others (like [Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(programming_language))) use [uniqueness typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_type).  Still others (like  [Clean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_(programming_language))) use [effect systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_system).  Of these I have a very, very limited exposure to Mercury only, so I can't really comment on details.  There's a [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=E725ADC5F4F4B360A1209DB64B3B2237?doi=10.1.1.17.935&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that details Clean's I/O system in depth, however, if you're interested in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my understanding, if you want to have side effects in a functional language, you have to code them explicitly.

Comment: However, Monads and do notation and sometimes "implicits" hide this for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Since side-effects break referential transparency, don't they go against the point of functional languages?

It depends on the functional language:

- [Standard ML](https://www.smlnj.org/sml.html) allows the liberal use of side-effects like most procedural languages e.g. Fortran, Algol, Pascal, C, etc.
- [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) restricts side-effects through the use of *abstract data types* like `IO`, `ST` and `STM`, which helps to preserve referential transparency.
- [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl/Clean) also restricts side-effects, but does this with its extended type system.
- The functional language *Coq* uses - [Gallina](https://deepspec.org/event/dsss17/lecture_appel.html) - provides [no access to side-effects](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/haskell/io.html) at all.

---

> How do functional languages model side-effects?

One approach which isn't regularly mentioned relies on *pseudo-data*: individual single-use abstract values conveyed in an accessible structured value (commonly a tree), with the side effects only occuring when each abstract value is initially used. For more information, see F. Warren Burton's [Nondeterminism with Referential Transparency in Functional Programming Language](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article-pdf/31/3/243/1157325/310243.pdf). An working example can also be found in GHC: its [`Unique`](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/unique) name-supply type.

But if the extra parameters needed to make *pseudo-data* work is just too annoying, it is [actually possible](https://www2.ki.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/research/diamond/hasfuse/index.html) to usefully combine I/O and its observable effects with non-strict semantics...if you don't really need referential transparency.